# How to get facebook user liked page name, category list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application where I need to get the **name, category list of user like pages.**
I have added 'user_likes' to my permission list and **successfully got the permission to access user like page list.**

What I want to know is how to access these details and assign them into variables?
I tried bellow code

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function (response) {
   FB.api('/me/likes', function(user) {
            if (user) {
                var pageCount = user.data.length; //just try to get the length to check wheter it works 
                // I want to add name and category into variables here
         });
       });
```

And it assign '184' to the pageCount which means it works. I want to access name and category list
 
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just used bellow code to get the data

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function (response) {
   FB.api('/me/likes', function(user) {
            if (user) {
                var pageCount = user.data.length; 
                var pageName = user.data[0].name;
                var pageCategory = user.data[0].category;            
         });
       });
```

This will assign the name and category of first liked page, use for loop to get all data